# Indy 10 sends data in 1024 chunks. How to increase chunk size?

Tags: linux, performance, tcp, lazarus, indy10

I have developed two softwares side by side.

One is a TCP client for iOS devices, which is developed in XCode,
the other one is a TCP server for Linux OS, which is developed in Lazarus using Indy 10 as the networking framework.

I can send data between the server and the client with no major problems,
however the speed of data transfer from the server to the client is an issue to me.

When sending data from the iOS client to the Linux server I get very good transfer speeds of up to 20 MB a second,
but when sending data from the Linux server to the iOS client I get only up to a hundred kilobytes a second (100kb).

Indy 10 sends data in 1024 byte chunks, and I can see that in my iOS app by using `NSLog()`.

**Question:** How can I change the behaviour of Indy 10 to send larger chunks at once?

**EDIT:**
I am using the following code to send a `TMemoryStream`:

```
procedure TMyClass.SendData(aData: TMemoryStream);
  var i: integer;
      ctx : TIdContext;
begin
  aData.Position := 0;
  with fIdTCP.Contexts.LockList do
  begin
    for i := 0 to Count -1 do //I'm broadcasting the data
    begin
      ctx := TIdContext(Items[i]);
      ctx.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:=true;
      ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(aData, aData.Size, false);
    end;

    ctx.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
    fIdTCP.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end   
end;
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question.  HOW are you sending data from Indy to iOS?  What method calls are you making? Are you using SSL/TLS? Things like that make a difference.  Indy does not use 1KB buffers unless you tell it to. If anything, its default buffer size is 32K instead.  So chances are that something outside of Indy is limiting the data size, depending on where your data is coming from and how you are sending it.

Comment: I updated the question and added code. It is true, the buffer size is 32K, I can measure it and change it, but still the iOS app receives 1024 kb chunks.

Comment: First, you should not be calling `WriteBufferClose()` without a previous `WriteBufferOpen()` (and you should not be using write buffering when sending `TStream` data). Second, `UnlockList()` needs to be in a `try/finally` block, as `Write()` can raise exceptions. If a client disconnects/fails, you will cause with a deadlock if you do not unlock the list. Third, if one client fails, you are not handling that, so you end up skipping all subsequent clients in your broadcast. And FYI, this is not the best way to handle TCP broadcasting with Indy.

Comment: In any case, `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` allocates a (default) 32K buffer and reads chunks of that size from the `TStream`, sending however many bytes were actually read as-is to the underlying socket. `TMemoryStream` does not have a 1024K limit on reads, and neither does Indy. But the underlying socket may impose 1024K limits on sends, depending on its internal buffer size. You can set that buffer size using `AContext.Binding.SetSocketOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDBUF, ...)`. Or try setting `AContext.Connection.Socket.UseNagle := False`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll do what you suggested. So how exactly does `SetSocketOpt`work and what should I write to change the internal buffer size?

Comment: Read the documentation for the Linux [`setsockopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) function, which Indy wraps. In fact, it actually says the socket's default send buffer size on Linux *IS* 1024 bytes. You would simply specify a different size, such as in the `OnConnect` event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did that inside OnConnect, but I still receive 1024 sized chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy is not the one limiting the size of the sent packets.  Its default buffer size is 32K (see the `TIdIOHandler.SendBufferSize` property) when reading from the `TMemoryStream` (which is limited only by available memory on reads) and then passes however many bytes were read to the underlying socket for sending.

Linux might be the one limiting the size of the sends.  The default send buffer size of the underlying socket can be 1024 bytes.  The Linux documentation states the following:

[socket - Linux socket interface](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)

> Socket options
>
> The socket options listed below can be set by using [`setsockopt(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) and read with [`getsockopt(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html) with the socket level set to `SOL_SOCKET` for all sockets.  Unless otherwise noted, `optval` is a pointer to an `int`.
>
> ...
>
> SO_SNDBUF
>   Sets or gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.  The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using `setsockopt(2)`, and this doubled value is returned by `getsockopt(2)`.  The default value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default` file and the maximum allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` file. **The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 2048**.

So check if your Linux's `wmem_default`/`wmem_max` configuration is limiting the transmitted packets to 1024 bytes or not.

You can use Indy's `TIdSocketHandle.SetSockOpt()` method to try to specify a different buffer size (within Linux's configured limits), eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdStackConsts;

procedure TMyForm.MyTCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  BufferSize: Integer;
begin
  BufferSize := ...;
  AContext.Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDBUF, BufferSize);
  AContext.Binding.GetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDBUF, BufferSize);
  // BufferSize now contains the ACTUAL buffer size used by the socket
  // which may be different than what you requested...
end;
```

If the buffer size is not being limited by Linux, then it is likely being limited by iOS when receiving the data.  Make sure your iOS app is not limiting its input buffer to 1024 bytes when reading from an `NSInputStream` in your `stream` event handler.

Comment: Both those Linux files say 212992. I have set UseNagle to false and and SetSockOpt to 2048, 8000 and even 212992, but still getting 1024 byte cunks.

Comment: As I explained, Indy reads 32K (by default) at a time from the `TStream`, passing 32K at a time (or whatever the stream actually returns) to the underlying socket. After that, it is out of Indy's hands. If the subsequent transmissions are smaller than that, the limitation has to be in Linux itself, or on your network. Either Linux, your WiFi router, or your cellular provider is breaking up the packets into smaller transmissions. TCP allows that.  Watch your network with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to see what is happening.

Comment: I copyied yor code, still 1024 byte chunks. I never had this problem when I used LNet for Lazarus, only with Indy 10, so to be honest, I don't think that theres anything wrong with my Linux config.

Comment: But, I can send very large data to indy, and indy receives the data in various sizes without problems.

Comment: Indy uses a 32K (default) buffer for receives.  It receives whatever the underlying socket decides to give.  The socket has an `SO_RCVBUF` buffer for receives. That buffer receives data from the network and gets copies into Indy's read buffer (which is then cached in Indy's `InputBuffer`, which your app then reads from).

Comment: Look, Indy has no 1024 byte limit in its buffering code. The data has to be getting limited at a lower level than Indy. I don't care what LNet is capable of. Unless you have LNet's source code, you don't know what it does internally. But you do have Indy's source code, so feel free to step into that code with a debugger if you want to see what `Write()` is actually doing. Put a breakpoint in `TIdStackUnix.WSSend()` or `TIdStackLibc.WSSend()` (whichever class is getting used in your installation) and you should see the `ABufferLength` parameter set to 32K (prior to the last chunk of the stream)

Comment: Yes I just don't understand where it is getting limited. Maybe it's the XCode NSInputStream that has its own limiting, I need to check that.
I check the Indy send buffer size with the following code: `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.SendBufferSize` and it returns `32768` so eveything seems fine.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is really on the *sending* side, that iOS itself is simply not *receiving* the data in 1024 byte chunks on its end? You really need to use a packet sniffer to see if the transmitted packets are actually 1024 bytes in size.  Can you show your iOS code that is receiving the data?

Comment: I checked the internals of the TCP class of my iOS app and that's where the limit was. Doh!!!! There was a 1 line very small variable which sets the buffer size, I can't believe I've missed it, it's been in front of my eyes all the time. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Please add a line on your answer which says "Make sure your iOS app is not limiting the input buffer of your NSInputStream inside the `stream` event.", and then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I have added the comment to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was not a waste of time, I learned something new at least.